# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftMetal.dylib on iOS 11(15A5304j) with Xcode 9 beta 6

Tags: ios11, snapkit, xcode9-beta5

I'm trying to provide **iOS 11** support to my existing project but when I launch my existing project, my app gets crash as soon as it launches with following error at Xcode console

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftMetal.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/46C09D9B-D37F-42D7-B0AF-76EB6E189727/myApp.app/Frameworks/SnapKit.framework/SnapKit
  Reason: image not found
```

I know there are lots of answer around this already but nothing worked for me.

**Note: I'm using iOS 11 iPad and Xcode-beta 5**

**Update 1**: this problem occurs on my iPad iOS11(15A5304j), on iPhone 6plus iOS 11(15A5327g) works fine.

Comment: Having the same problem on beta 6.

Comment: @JasonGritman update your iOS 11 build with the latest. That's how I got rid of this crash.